# Add People in conference using Twilio

Tags: php, codeigniter, twilio, twilio-php

I having a problem in Twilio conferences. Is it possible to add a participant in conference while the agent is in the same conference? I tried to hold the Participants and make a call. It was successful to hold the participants, but I can't dial a number while I am in the conference. The code below is to hold the participant in the conference.

```
function HoldConference_group($roomName, $muteCallSid, $muteStatus)
{
    $client = $this->InitializeTwillio();
    $conferenceSid = "";
    foreach ($client->account->conferences->getIterator(0, 50, array("Status" => "in-progress", "FriendlyName" => $roomName)) as $conference)
    {
        $conferenceSid = $conference->sid;
    }

    $participant = $client->account->conferences->get($conferenceSid)->participants->get($muteCallSid);
    $participant->update(array("Hold" => $muteStatus));
}
```

This is my code in controller, I am using php in codeigniter

```
public function redirect_to_conference()
{
    $client = $this->init_client();

    //The Call sid that i pass is the parent call sid which is me so i will be transferred to the conference
    $call = $client->account->calls->get($_POST["CallSid"]);
    $call->update(array(
        "Url" => HTTP_BASE_URL."agent/call_controls/forward_conference",
        "Method" => "POST"
    ));

}
```

This is where I pass the room name so that the room name will be the name of the conference

```
function GroupConference($roomName)
{
    //NEED TO CHANGE IT TO INPUT BY AGENT
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml;
    $response->say(
        'You have joined the conference.',
        ['voice' => 'alice', 'language' => 'en-GB']
    );
    $dial = $response->dial();
    $dial->conference(
            $roomName, 
            array(
                'startConferenceOnEnter' => 'true',
                'endConferenceOnExit' => 'false',
                'muted' => 'false',
                'record' => 'record-from-start',
                'waitUrl' => 'http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.ambient',
            )
        );

    print $response;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using so far? It is possible, perhaps I can help if there is some code I can start from? Also, what is the exact user flow you expect?

Comment: I tried to hold the conference and dial another but i cant achieve this while i am in the conference. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've added your code to put someone on hold (at least, the person in the last in progress conference on hold) but that has nothing to do with the rest of the experience. How would you like the person on the call to add someone else? What have you tried?

Comment: i have edited my post

Comment: How do you actually want the admin to add a caller? Press something on their phone? Do something in a web browser?

Comment: The admin will dial a phone number in a browser and if the caller answer it the admin will add the caller to conference.

Comment: And is it possible for the admin to add himself to his conference using his friendlyname?

Comment: Because what happening now is just the admin is just transferring his caller to conference. what if the admin wants to go to his conference? is that possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123939/discussion-between-jann-anthony-briza-and-philnash).

Comment: I'm in the chat room now